# How do I make a PC .local instead of IP?

Tags: ethernet, avahi

I have this problem at the office.

I have 3 PCs that are connected by ethernet cables and one that isn't because that one is connected without a cable, it's wireless.

The weird thing is that all the PCs are detected by a `hostname.local`,
the other one which is the one that is wireless it can't be identified, except with just IP.
How do I make it get identified and be `.local`?

Can anyone help me display this PC as `.local`? 
wired:

`ifconfig` on Wired PC:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:0a:a9:9f:22:8c  
          inet addr:192.168.1.65  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ca0a:a9ff:fe9f:228c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:458841 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:297827 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:609175794 (609.1 MB)  TX bytes:33497578 (33.4 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fb500000-fb520000
```

`ifconfig` on Wireless PC:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 1c:3e:84:14:77:1d 
          inet addr:192.168.1.103 Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1e3e:84ff:fe14:771d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
          RX packets:20252 errors:75 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:293591
          TX packets:20197 errors:24 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9528535 (9.5 MB) TX bytes:4115883 (4.1 MB)
          Interrupt:17
```

Comment: "connected by ethernet except one" How is the other PC connected then? Wireless on the same Layer 2 subnet? Or remotely? What are you trying to accomplish in the first place? Do you need a VPN perhaps? I mean... please provide a lot more information in your question (edit it!).

Comment: didi t :P sorry, i got bad english

Comment: If you have your wireless network connected to your wired as it is supposed to (flat layer 2 network), then it will just work. However, I think you have another routed network (layer 3 routed network) for your wireless. To confirm this, post the output of `ifconfig` on a wired PC and on the wireless PC into this question. `.local` is a zeroconf feature for which you need to be on the very same Layer 2 segment.

Comment: . :D so uhh there you go.

Comment: Looks like both are in the `192.168.1.0/24` subnet, so it's *likely* you are using a flat L2 network. If you can reach both devices by IP address directly (e.g. `ping 192.168.1.103` from the wired pc and `ping 192.168.1.65` from the wireless PC), then it's still possible that some networking device (e.g. abusing router as AP) is blocking this mDNS traffic.

Comment: mmmmk ill see about that, maybe ill reinstall ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Installing and running Avahi will make it visible via Zeroconf, which means that other machines on the LAN that use Zeroconf will be able to access it as `<hostname>.local`.

Comment: Same way you install all packages and run all daemons on Ubuntu.

Comment: On the one that needs the .local name.

Comment: Ignacio, can you give me the command? to see how to do it..

Comment: I can't, since I don't actually use Ubuntu.

Comment: .___. how do you...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't think he still needs to install this package as the hostname resolution already works on the other machines. However, it could be possible that it is removed or that a very lightweight Ubuntu in installed on that wireless machine.

Comment: @gertvdijk: Avahi does announcement, not detection.