# How do I use avahi to display system as .local

Tags: avahi

Installing and running Avahi will make it visible via Zeroconf, which means that other machines on the LAN that use Zeroconf will be able to access it as .local.
how do I do that?

Comment: This is installed by default on Ubuntu. You don't have to do anything unless you have installed a minimal version of Ubuntu or if you have removed a zerconf/avahi package deliberately. See this Q&A on U&L SE: [Detect other machine's address in link local?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57577/23363)

Comment: well, the problem with the pc is still not fixed. it wont display in .local but with ip it does

Comment: This is probably related to your other question: [How do I make a PC .local instead of IP?](http://askubuntu.com/q/324022/88802). You haven't provided the details I requested earlier in order to say this has to do with it ([as I commented](http://askubuntu.com/questions/324022/how-do-i-make-a-pc-local-instead-of-ip#comment412024_324026) to the answer there).